# finding types embedding another type using x/tools/go/packages

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

suppose i have below code,

```golang
package w

import "log"

type Z struct {
    log.Logger
}

type Y struct {} // skip this type
```

I want to programmatically lookup for the type `Z`, identified by the fact it embeds `log.Logger`, if it does not i want to skip the declaration, using https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/packages

Currently I have been able to write below code,

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/token"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    "golang.org/x/tools/go/packages"
)

func main() {
    inputFile := os.Getenv("GOFILE")
    cwd, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(inputFile)
    fmt.Println(cwd)

    cfg := &packages.Config{
        // Mode:       packages.NeedName | packages.NeedFiles | packages.NeedSyntax | packages.LoadTypes,
        Mode:       packages.NeedSyntax | packages.LoadTypes,
        BuildFlags: []string{"-tags=sqlg"},
    }
    pkgs, err := packages.Load(cfg, cwd)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "load: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    if packages.PrintErrors(pkgs) > 0 {
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    for _, pkg := range pkgs {
        fmt.Println(pkg.ID, pkg.GoFiles)
        for _, s := range pkg.Syntax {
            file := pkg.Fset.File(s.Pos())
            if filepath.Base(file.Name()) != inputFile {
                continue
            }
            for _, d := range s.Decls {
                switch x := d.(type) {
                case *ast.GenDecl:
                    if x.Tok == token.TYPE {
                        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", x.Specs)
                    }
                case *ast.FuncDecl:
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I dont like it very much because i am digging the syntax tree looking up for GenDecl, then Specs etc etc

Previously, using the package loader `https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/go/loader` it was possible to load up type inference, search the types per package and check for interface compatilibity; it appeears to me i would like something similar.

How to use the new packages package to lookup for types given they embed a specific type with simplicity ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Var.Embedded` in [`go/types`](https://pkg.go.dev/go/types#Var.Embedded) package.

You can use use `golang.org/x/tools/go/loader` to Load the package and get types info, then use `Type.Underlying` and interface cast to filter-out struct type, then use iterate over `Struct.Filed` to get the `Var` of the field, and check the `Var`.

Comment: I think i have  to mixin your answer with the packages.package.Types.RelativeTo as demonstrated in https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/b1c90890d22a/go/packages/gopackages/main.go#L194 I did not accept your (super useful) answer because it is based on the deprecated loader package.

Comment: @mh-cbon I was not aware that loader package got deprecated. But I think it is just a problem of getting `go/types`'s useful type info. Go's ast tooling packages currently really looks like a maze and poorly documented.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [leaf bebop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9143962/leaf-bebop) answer I was able to write a much shorter program, the original post does not show but in v1 i have 8 levels of indentation to lookup for the embedded property of a struct.

This is inspired by the demonstration provided at https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20201226215659-b1c90890d22a/go/packages/gopackages

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/types"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/tools/go/packages"
)

func main() {
    inputFile := os.Getenv("GOFILE")
    cwd, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(inputFile)
    fmt.Println(cwd)

    cfg := &packages.Config{
        // Mode:       packages.NeedName | packages.NeedFiles | packages.NeedSyntax | packages.LoadTypes,
        Mode:       packages.NeedSyntax | packages.LoadTypes,
    }
    pkgs, err := packages.Load(cfg, cwd)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "load: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    if packages.PrintErrors(pkgs) > 0 {
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    for _, pkg := range pkgs {
        // qual := types.RelativeTo(pkg.Types)
        scope := pkg.Types.Scope()
        for _, name := range scope.Names() {
            obj := scope.Lookup(name)
            if obj != nil && obj.Type() != nil && obj.Type().Underlying() != nil {
                // obj is types.Named, 
                // obj.Type() is types.TypeName
                // obj.Type().Underlying() exposes the types.Struct which 
                // gives access to the desired types.Var.Embedded()
                st, ok := obj.Type().Underlying().(*types.Struct)
                if !ok {
                    continue
                }
                for i := 0; i < st.NumFields(); i++ {
                    f := st.Field(i)
                    if f.Embedded() && strings.HasSuffix(f.Type().String(), "log.Logger") {
                        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", f)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I believe it exists a shorter version which uses the visitor pattern, but i have not found it yet.

In this version i still rely on string comparison to type check the property, this is something that can be improved later using type inference.

Comment: `go/types` also provides `Identical` and `Assignable` (which I am not familiar enough to tell edge case difference, though I would say use `Identical`) to compare `Type`, which can be retrieved through `Var.Type` method, to get rid of string comparison. How to load the imported type, is another question though.